# How to fix Whatsapp font awesome not working

Tags: font-awesome

All my icons are working just fine except the whatsapp one which displays nothing. Kindly assist.

```
<i class="fab fa-whatsapp-square"></i>
```

Comment: Could you put up a working snippet to show us the problem? In particular how you are getting fontawesome -  which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that Fontawesome version 4.7 or earlier is being used.

While there was a whatsapp icon in 4.3 onwards, there was not a whatsapp-square.

If you do upgrade to version 5 be aware that the way icons are rendered in the document is different from previous versions with SVG icons being used and the  elements replaced.